# Android Studio/Kotlin: Get names of all Activities with category LAUNCHER and action MAIN

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am a beginner in Kotlin/ AS and i want to make a button that, when clicked, redirects to another activity that has a ListView that shows the names of all activities with category LAUNCHER and action MAIN. I was trying to find answers on my own for quite some time, but im stuck on this.

The layouts and redirects are familiar to me at the moment, but i dont know how i can get what im asking. Maybe through **PackageManager** ?

I know this is a cheesy question, but thank you very much in advance for helping in any way

Comment: Hi, can help to elaborate your expectation? somehow I wonder there are 2 expectation, Redirect to Activity and Get names of all activities

Comment: I am expecting for a function to return all names of all activities. The button will redirect me to the new Activity in which a ListView is present. My idea was in this new activity to create a private function to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this, by using Package Manager and ResolveInfo, like the following code

```
private fun getActivities(): MutableList<String> {
    val resultList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    val mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    val resolveInfos: List<ResolveInfo> = 
    packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0)
    for(info in resolveInfos){
        if(info.activityInfo.name != null){
            resultList.add(info.activityInfo.name.toString())
        }
    }
    return resultList
}
```